# Different routing behavior between Web API and Azure Function HTTP Trigger Problem

Tags: c#, routes, azure-functions, .net-5

I've spent the entire morning trying to figure this out. I have a Web API project (.NET 5) that has a number of controllers. I'm being tasked to divide it out into microservices using Azure Functions instead of an app service. There are three endpoints in one controller:

```cs
[HttpGet("history/{country}/{stateProvince}/{countyRegion}")]
IActionResult GetByCounty(string country, string stateProvince, string countyRegion)

[HttpGet("history/{country}/{stateProvince}")]
IActionResult GetByState(string country, string stateProvince)

[HttpGet("history/postalcodes/{country}/{postalCode}")]
IActionResult GetByPostalCode(string country, string postalCode)
```

This is all well and good and everything works as expected. In the function app, I defined the three HTTP triggers:

```cs
HttpResponseData GetByCounty([HttpTrigger(Route = "history/{country}/{stateProvince}/{countyRegion}")]

HttpResponseData GetByPostalCode([HttpTrigger(Route = "history/postalcodes/{country}/{postalCode}")]

HttpResponseData GetByState([HttpTrigger(Route = "history/{country}/{stateProvince}")]
```

GetByState and GetByCounty work fine. However, when trying to get by postal code in the function app, the function GetByCounty is being executed. The Web API app is honoring the static text **"postalcodes"** in the route. The functions app is not. It sees four levels in the path and picks the first one alphabetically which happens to be GetByCounty.

Other than adding an unnecessary path to get the number of levels to be unique, is there a way to make this work so the correct HTTP trigger is executed?

- Changing GetByPostalCode to "hickory/postalcodes/{country}/{postalcode} works
- Changing GetByPostalCode to "postalcodes/history/{country}/{postalcode} works
- Adding an additional path level "history/postalcodes/countries/{country}/{postalcode} works

But this breaks the API in terms of compatibility which isn't a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions and Web API look pretty similar to each other as both take an HTTP request, process it and return a response and it seems to be Web API can be easily migrated to Azure Function. But,

**HTTP Trigger Function is not equal to Web API Action**

- Each Azure Function has a **static modifier by design** whereas the WebAPI don't have the Static Modifier.
- Also Azure Functions are extensions of Azure WebJobs, WebJobs can without the static modifier.

---

- A Web API Controller internally creates an HttpContext instance to handle data like headers, cookies, session querystrings and request body, etc where the HTTPContext instance works as internal property so any action can directly access it.
- Azure Function takes a different HTTP request/response from Web API, which takes the parameter as a HttpRequestMessage instance. It doesn't look after cookies or sessions and it just handles headers, querystrings and request body.

---

### In terms of Routing:

- Some decorators like `HttpGet, HttpPut, HttpPatch and HttpDelete` on each action to declare which HTTP Verbs take action were put by combining with the Route decorator in Web API.
- And also the base URL will be defined on the controller level of Web API.

---

- Here is the 2 files that gets created with Azure Functions Creation i.e., `function.json` and `host.json`.
- `function.json`contains routes of each function HTTP action definition. With this definition, **different functions having the same route URI can handle requests based on HTTP verbs.**
- Here is no controller in Azure Functions. So, the functions endpoint URI defined in `host.json` with the default value is `api` but we can modify the route URI using `host.json` like:

```
    {
    "http": { 
    "routePrefix": "" // prefix, "api", is removed.
      }    
    }
```

---

Azure Functions are mostly beneficial in these type of scenarios over Web API like:

- If the Web API is designed for Microservices Architecture.
- If the Web API takes long time for response.
- If the Web API needs a significant amount of efforts for refactoring the architecture.

Comment: Unfortunately, this provides no useful information. What I've been able to dig up is the function name is used to determine search order
``` c#
[Function("This Name Determines Search Order")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> MyFunctionName(...)
{
...
}
```
So it's possible to alter which trigger is identified as a match playing around with the sort order.